# How to decrypt a MD5 hash

Tags: vb.net

I have used the following function to encrypt my password:

```
HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(Password, "MD5")
```

Now I want to decrypt the password again.

**Note** I'm showing the encrypted password in a grid-view and I want to decrypt it when the particular row goes in edit mode.

Comment: you cannot **decrypt** Hashes ... and you should not be able to decrypt passwords anyway. The reason is simple: a Hash maps strings to some number/id but there can be collisions - different inputs with the same output - so the *function* is not *injective*

Comment: Also if this is going to be a real product with security in mind please get some expert-help - I can already tell that your product will be not secure at all! (For example: you should add **salt**s to your passwords before hashing and MD5 is a [**bad choice**](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure))

Comment: @shafay use [rijnadael managed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to encrypt your passwords

Comment: I would say **no** use [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) or something similar ... but really: don't implement crypto/security yourself (there are only so many people around where this rule does not apply - me excluded) - [see here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/31846#31846?newreg=8903554aeee540a780e0fe99bb2ea4e0) (this link was easily reachable from the discussion I linked above - but so be it)

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is "you can't"

The idea of hashing is to generate a "safe" code from the real password, where that code can be stored in clear text; in a database (or text file) somewhere where other users might be seeing it somehow.

When someone tries to login, your system would compute another hash from the new login and then compare with the existing hash from your existing database, if the hash matches, then you know it's the correct password and then you can allow them to login, otherwise, it's not the same password / login-failed.

The reason why you cannot reverse the hash is because a hash is computed by doing the following steps:

1) Taking the password into some algorithm to:
2) Generate a very large string, then:
3) Chop that string and:
4) Take a part of it as your "hash"

So you see, even if you are superman in decoding and can figure the algorithm out, and know the hash code, and managed to reverse it back into the original form, then you would still have parts of the password missing, hence unsuccessful.

This is why Hashes are secure.

I hope this explains it.

Answer (score 2):

you can make encrypt and decrypt function like this to encrypt and decrypt your text , and further u can use as per your need to display the decrypt text
here is the function

```
Public Function Encrypt(ByVal plainText As String) As String

    Dim passPhrase As String = "yourPassPhrase"
    Dim saltValue As String = "mySaltValue"
    Dim hashAlgorithm As String = "MD5"

    Dim passwordIterations As Integer = 2
    Dim initVector As String = "@1B2c3D4e5F6g7H8"
    Dim keySize As Integer = 256

    Dim initVectorBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(initVector)
    Dim saltValueBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(saltValue)

    Dim plainTextBytes As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText)


    Dim password As New PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, saltValueBytes, hashAlgorithm, passwordIterations)

    Dim keyBytes As Byte() = password.GetBytes(keySize \ 8)
    Dim symmetricKey As New RijndaelManaged()

    symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC

    Dim encryptor As ICryptoTransform = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes)

    Dim memoryStream As New MemoryStream()
    Dim cryptoStream As New CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)

    cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length)
    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()
    Dim cipherTextBytes As Byte() = memoryStream.ToArray()
    memoryStream.Close()
    cryptoStream.Close()
    Dim cipherText As String = Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes)
    Return cipherText
End Function
```

and for decrypt use this

```
Public Function Decrypt(ByVal cipherText As String) As String
    Dim passPhrase As String = "yourPassPhrase"
    Dim saltValue As String = "mySaltValue"
    Dim hashAlgorithm As String = "MD5"

    Dim passwordIterations As Integer = 2
    Dim initVector As String = "@1B2c3D4e5F6g7H8"
    Dim keySize As Integer = 256
    ' Convert strings defining encryption key characteristics into byte
    ' arrays. Let us assume that strings only contain ASCII codes.
    ' If strings include Unicode characters, use Unicode, UTF7, or UTF8
    ' encoding.
    Dim initVectorBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(initVector)
    Dim saltValueBytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(saltValue)

    ' Convert our ciphertext into a byte array.
    Dim cipherTextBytes As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText)

    ' First, we must create a password, from which the key will be 
    ' derived. This password will be generated from the specified 
    ' passphrase and salt value. The password will be created using
    ' the specified hash algorithm. Password creation can be done in
    ' several iterations.
    Dim password As New PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, saltValueBytes, hashAlgorithm, passwordIterations)

    ' Use the password to generate pseudo-random bytes for the encryption
    ' key. Specify the size of the key in bytes (instead of bits).
    Dim keyBytes As Byte() = password.GetBytes(keySize \ 8)

    ' Create uninitialized Rijndael encryption object.
    Dim symmetricKey As New RijndaelManaged()

    ' It is reasonable to set encryption mode to Cipher Block Chaining
    ' (CBC). Use default options for other symmetric key parameters.
    symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC

    ' Generate decryptor from the existing key bytes and initialization 
    ' vector. Key size will be defined based on the number of the key 
    ' bytes.
    Dim decryptor As ICryptoTransform = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes)

    ' Define memory stream which will be used to hold encrypted data.
    Dim memoryStream As New MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes)

    ' Define cryptographic stream (always use Read mode for encryption).
    Dim cryptoStream As New CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read)

    ' Since at this point we don't know what the size of decrypted data
    ' will be, allocate the buffer long enough to hold ciphertext;
    ' plaintext is never longer than ciphertext.
    Dim plainTextBytes As Byte() = New Byte(cipherTextBytes.Length - 1) {}

    ' Start decrypting.
    Dim decryptedByteCount As Integer = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length)

    ' Close both streams.
    memoryStream.Close()
    cryptoStream.Close()

    ' Convert decrypted data into a string. 
    ' Let us assume that the original plaintext string was UTF8-encoded.
    Dim plainText As String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, decryptedByteCount)

    ' Return decrypted string.   
    Return plainText
End Function
```

and call the function  you will get the result.

Comment: the `PasswordDeriveBytes` is indeed a good idea (just not with `MD5`) - what is not a good idea is to provide the **salt** as an constant value and an even worse idea is to provide the *passPhrase* as constant - what would be a good idea is to use this to **hash** the users password (with an random salt) and save the result and the salt - **no** you will not be able to decipher it - but as I said you **should not** be able to do this anyway (as this is exactly what a attacker would want to do once he got his hands on your hashes)

Comment: there is even a **security note** on the official docs to [`PasswordDeriveBytes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.passwordderivebytes(v=vs.110).aspx): "Never hard-code a password within your source code. Hard coded passwords can be retrieved from an assembly using the Ildasm.exe (IL Disassembler) tool, a hex editor, or by simply opening up the assembly in a text editor like notepad.exe." ;)